# How do I configure Fiddler 4 to decrypt HTTPS traffic under Windows 7?

Tags: fiddler

I have gone through the instructions on the Fiddler site. I have the Fiddler root cert trusted in Windows (using Windows 7), but when I connect a browser to HTTPS sites I get this:

"Fiddler's HTTPS Decryption feature is enabled, but this specific tunnel was configured not to be decrypted. Settings can be found inside Tools > Options > HTTPS."

When I check that option page, everything looks ok.

[image]

Comment: Did you accept the certificate installation warning and install it? Do you enable to change proxy settings in Windows? Download the updated version of Fiddler: https://telerik-fiddler.s3.amazonaws.com/fiddler/FiddlerSetup.exe

Comment: I did accept the certificate installation warning. I'm not sure what you mean about the proxy settings.

Comment: Fiddler change the proxy IP in Windows to 127.0.0.1. So go to internet settings and check if Fddler configures proxy in your machine automatically.

Comment: Looks like that's been set.